# Update .babelrc to Add JavaScript File Paths to Transpile

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I used Babel to transpile ES6 JavaScript to ES5 for:
https://hollyw00d.github.io/Accessible-ES6-JavaScript-Tabs/

I can't figure out how to update my `.babelrc` file to automatically transpile a specific ES6 file to a specific ES5 file.

**What code do I add into my `.babelrc` file to do that? Is this even possible?**

Here's the contents of my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "minify"
  ]
}
```

Here's the command I do on my Mac's iTerm to transpile my ES6 file into my ES5 file:
`npx babel ./assets/js/scripts.js --out-file ./assets/js/scripts.min.js`

Here's the npm modules I've installed locally in the directory for this project:

```
├── @babel/cli@7.10.5
├── @babel/core@7.10.5
├── @babel/preset-env@7.10.4
├── babel-preset-minify@0.5.1
└── core-js@3.6.5
```

Comment: So currently running that command does not work?

Comment: Yes, running ```npx babel ./assets/js/scripts.js --out-file ./assets/js/scripts.min.js``` works.  

I'm wondering if I can update the ```.babelrc``` with file paths so I just need to run ```npx babel``` to convert ```scripts.js``` into ```scripts.min.js```.

Answer (score 1):

Babel's `.babelrc` files are for configuring what transformations to perform on given input files but do not cover what input files or what output files will be processed, so this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answers @loganfsmyth, which is I can't do what I wanted to with Babel's ```.babelrc``` file alone.  

Instead I'll need to use something like webpack (https://webpack.js.org/) to add in an ES6 input file path and an ES5 output file path in a separate config file (like ```webpack.config.js``` for webpack).